# Figure out process producing strange debugger output: "Key arival and hook"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, winapi, process, output

On my computer, whenever I press or release a key while using Microsoft Visual Studio debugger, I keep seeing messages like this:

> Key arival and hook

(spelling intended)

Pressing and releasing enter, I see messages like this:

> Key arival and hookKey arival and hook

This is within any app I'm debugging.  Virus/spyware software have done scans - not sure what else could explain it.

Is there any way to determine the process that is sending these debug messages?

I understand this is an edge case question - I figured only programmers would be able to help with a problem that would only affect programmers.

Comment: Since Visual Studio only outputs debug messages from the debuggee, you already know, which process is sending the output. That doesn't help a whole lot, though, because you still don't know, which process *installed* the malware. If you run [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview), I'm pretty sure you'll see this output from just about any process.

Comment: [This forum post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32946-Windows-debuging-output) says it's coming from the ATI video driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding out the answer through this: http://www.devpia.com/MAEUL/Contents/Detail.aspx?BoardID=50&MAEULNo=20&no=854092&ref=854092

Essentially, some ASUS overclocking tool (TurboV EVO) was producing these messages.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, if so, would you please mark it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)